# How to detect "required" popups in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying use puppeteer detect a required-pup-up that comes when you try to submit a form that has required inputs without a value. Here is an example:

[image: A photo of what I was trying to describe]

The source code of the HTML file I have is the following:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" required placeholder="nothing in here">    
</form>
```

The source code for opening puppeteer, clicking and submitting on the element is the following:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function run(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("http://localhost:8000");
    
    var inputElement = await page.waitForSelector("input");
    await inputElement.click();
    await inputElement.press("Enter");
    
    // Bespoke pop-up should appear here

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
}

run();
```

To see if this might also be covered by the same event handler as "dialog", I tried adding a listener for that as well:

```js
page.on("dialog", e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Judging by the fact that the console stayed empty, I'm assuming nothing happened. Is there a way to detect such a pop-up, or to detect the fact that the form has not been submitted? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do a quick validation yourself before you hit "Enter" there to see if the inputs are valid, something like:

```js
for (let i = 0, els = await page.$$('form'); i < els.length; i++) {
    if (await els[i].$eval('input', a => a.required && !a.validity.valid)) {
        console.log("This form is missing a value and will not submit");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, of course, depending on expected behavior of this form's submission, you can wait for either `waitForResponse` or `waitForNavigation` to indicate success, and fail if you don't see that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just detect all the input elements, that have `required` in the form and fill them in with predetermined values like in the code below.

code :

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" required placeholder="something1">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="something2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="something3">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="something4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="something5">
            <input type="text" required placeholder="something6">  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">            
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil : 'domcontentloaded'});
    await page.waitForSelector('body');

    let data = [
        { loc: "something1", value: "1" },
        { loc: "something2", value: "2" },
        { loc: "something4", value: "4" },
        { loc: "something6", value: "6" },
    ];

    let reqs = await page.$$('form > input[type=text]');
    for (let req of reqs) {
        const chk = await req.evaluate(el => {return el.hasAttribute("required")});
        if (chk) {
            let placeholderVal = await req.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('placeholder'));
            let res = data.find(obj => obj.loc === placeholderVal);
            await req.type(res.value);
        } 
    }

})().catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this goal by using my Puppeteer wrapper library.

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai

[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html#isrequired)

```js
import { getElements, isRequired, mapAsync, type } from 'bubanai-ng';

    const inputs = await getElements(page, 'input');
    await mapAsync(inputs, async (input) => {
      if (isRequired(page, input)) {
        await type('text', page, input)
      }
    });
```

Comment: Does this just check if the input is required or does it also check if that popup appears?

Comment: @Brillenschlumpf AFAIK pop-up is built-in browser function. If element has property `required` - this pop-up would appear if field entered data does not match condition and there is no need to verify that separately. Provided code just fills in all `required` fields with text.

Comment: `isRequired` itself checks if element has property `required`